# RadDateTimePicker Change Calendar to Month View

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-raddatepicker

is there a way for me to format the `raddatetimepicker` to have a month and year view on selection view?..

something like this..

[image]

what I have tried so far is this:

```
dateStartDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
dateStartDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateStartDate.CustomFormat = "MMMM - yyyy";
dateStartDate.ShowUpDown = true;
```

[image]

but it doesn't show the view anymore instead gives me an `up` and `down` button to change the month....

I am Using `C#` as my language and `telerik`.....
and this is a windows form...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have read this or not, but I think it'd certainly help point you to the right direction.

[Customize RadCalendar Programmatically](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/editors/datetimepicker/how-to/customize-radcalendar-programmatically#customize-radcalendar-programmatically)

Essentially, you will need to get a reference of RadCalendar from your RadDateTimePicker control, and from there, you can start customising its calendar view based on your own need.

```
RadDateTimePickerCalendar calendarBehavior = this.dateStartDate.DateTimePickerElement.GetCurrentBehavior() as RadDateTimePickerCalendar;
RadCalendar calendar = calendarBehavior.Calendar as RadCalendar;
RadCalendarElement calendarElement = calendar.CalendarElement as RadCalendarElement;
```

Update

In your case, I think you will be looking at the ZoomLevel of RadClaendar. 
Something like this

```
calendar.HeaderNavigationMode = HeaderNavigationMode.Zoom;
calendar.ZoomLevel = ZoomLevel.Months;
```

[Customize Zoom Navigation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/calendar/customizing-behavior/customizing-zoom-navigation)

Comment: this seems interesting and I haven't read this yet.... so is it possible to remove the calendar days and replace it with months?

Comment: it appears that `telerik.UI.RadCalendar` does not contain a definition  `HeaderNavigationMode`... same with `ZoomLevel`...

Comment: @SamTengWong well would it be possible for you to update your telerik library? Not sure what version you are on though.

Comment: it's 2013 version....., I cannot upgrade it..,I need permission from the company to do it... what version of telerik will support `HeaderNavigationMode` and `ZoomLevel`?

Comment: @SamTengWong Well you might wanna browser through the release history. http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/winforms/release-history